# input box not filled with the selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-form

I am using react-dates library of airbnb for date picker. However, its now working while using it along with redux form. When i click on the select date button, calendar pops up . While selecting the date, the input box is shown empty instead of selected date.

> My problem is the selected date is not shown on the input box.

**Here is my code**

```
const renderDateRangePicker = ({
  input,
  focused,
  onFocusChange,
}) => (
  <SingleDatePicker
    id="date_input"
    onDateChange={(value) => input.onChange(value.date)}
    onFocusChange={onFocusChange}
    focused={focused}
    date={(input.value && input.value.date) || null}
    className="form-control"
  />
);

onFocusChange({ focused }) {
  this.setState({ focused });
}

const { focused } = this.state;

<Field
  name="Fecha"
  onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
  focused={focused}
  component={renderDateRangePicker}
/>
```

How can i show the selected date on the input box in a way that the selected date is preserved too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your onDateChange function and date props as following:

```
onDateChange={(value) => input.onChange(value)} 
date = {input.value || null}
```

This should solve your solution.